# Symfony assert collection either or

Tags: validation, symfony

I have a Symfony assert collection in which I have two fields, I need **at least** one of these two fields to be present, the problem I am having is that in a collection all items are required unless set as optional, but any validations inside optional are not fired unless you have provided the field. Any ideas on how I can implement an either or type validator?

**Thanks!**

As an aside here is a quick idea of how I pictured it working, but even with validation specified, required still gets fired first.

```
new Assert\Collection([
    'html' => [
        new Assert\Callback([function() {

                $data = $this->getData();

                return isset($data['html']) or isset($data['plain']);
            }])
    ]
    'plain' => [ 
        new Assert\Callback([function() {

                $data = $this->getData();

                return isset($data['html']) or isset($data['plain']);
            }])
    ]
])
```

Answer (score 0):

When only one is really required out of two you cannot state that both are required per se.
You'll have to set both optional and after that make sure that at least one is set. I highly recommend to write your own Custom Validation for it.

See how it's done here: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/validation/custom_constraint.html

Comment: How would I use this new custom validator? I have no entity to attach it too

Comment: How do you plan to use your Assert\Collection?